# Gaussian expectation of an exponential function

Tags: probability-distributions

I am struggling to prove this,
$$
\int \mathcal{N}_\mathbf{x}(\mu,\Sigma)e^{a^T\mathbf{x}}d\mathbf{x} = e^{{a^T\mu}+\frac 12a^T\Sigma a}
$$

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Math.StackExchange. Your question is lacking in context. In an edit to this question you should provide the source in which this integral is stated. Also, for us to not rework anything you have done already, I suggest you edit the question with your progress so far.

Answer (score 1):

*Complete the square* in the exponent, that is, integrate the identity
$$
\mathcal{N}_\mathbf x(\mu,\Sigma)\cdot\mathrm e^{a^T\mathbf x}=\mathrm e^{a^T\mu+\frac 12a^T\Sigma a}\cdot\mathcal{N}_\mathbf x(\mu+\Sigma a,\Sigma).
$$